# Synchronous call retrofit 2 and return recyclerview in Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-alertdialog

I am having a question as to how can I make a call using retrofit2 to return in my Alertdialog a Recyclerview list?

I tried to use the call retrofit2 with the progress bar, but a returned null pointer exception is still returned.

```
public class CtePresenter {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private ServiceOSB service;
    private String authToken;

    public CtePresenter(Context context) {
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        this.dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        this.service = ServiceOSB.getInstance(Prefs.getAmbiente(context));
        this.authToken = Prefs.getAuthToken(context);
    }

    public void listaCliente(final RequestListener<RetListaCliente> listener) {
        dialog.setMessage("Carregando...");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        try {
            service.getCteService().listaCliente(authToken).enqueue(new RequestCallback<RetListaCliente>(listener, dialog));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(Util.TAG_LOG, e.getMessage());
            listener.onError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    searchRemetente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            final List<RetListaCliente.Cliente> lstCliente = new ArrayList<>();
            CtePresenter ctePresenter = new CtePresenter(getActivity());
            ctePresenter.listaCliente(new RequestListener<RetListaCliente>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(RetListaCliente response) {
                    for (RetListaCliente.Cliente c : response.getClientes()) {
                        lstCliente.add(c);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String error) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onUnauthoried(String error) {

                }
            });
            searchRemetenteDestinatario(v, lstCliente);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: use `execute()` instead of `enqueue()` to make a synchronous call with Retrofit 2. If you want help with the crash pls provide the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear if you need a synchronous event since it will work if you are using the callbacks correctly.

`onSuccess` is not guaranteed to run in any order 
before  `searchRemetenteDestinatario` uses that list

You need to move it inside the listener callback method if you want data to be in the list

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(RetListaCliente response) {
    lstCliente.clear();
    for (RetListaCliente.Cliente c : response.getClientes()) {
        lstCliente.add(c);
    }
    // searchRemetenteDestinatario
}
```

The nullpointerexception does not appear to be related to a progress dialog, so you'll have to clarify that